# Bootstrap 3 site: migrate to Wordpress or Password set up

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I (pretty much an advanced beginner) created about a 10-page site using Bootstrap 3. It all works great thankfully.
Now client wants to password protect entry (either have all users uniquely register or have one entry password for all).
My problem: I don't know how to set up a password code.
Possible solution: Move all content and CSS to a Wordpress template that will need child theme creation etc...This doesn't seem straightforward either.

Of the two devils I face to beat, which do you suggest (unless there is an easier path?)?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO it would be easier to learn to build wordpress templates than learn to build user management systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is another path: using .htaccess to password-protect files or directories.

This only works if you are using apache! There are alternatives for other web servers (nginx, lighttpd, etc).

Start out here:
http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

Comment: I'll have to check on my access (no pun intended) to htaccess. I'm on 1and1 (ugh) and not sure if they allow your suggested fix.

Comment: Looks like it's allowed for at least some 1and1 products - "For packages with SSH access" http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/linux-c85098/htaccess-c37776/manually-password-protect-your-filesfolders-linux-a777001.html

Comment: If you don't have access to that, though, Wordpress will probably not work either

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to WordPress really isn't necessary for this, but your options may be dependent on the environment in which your client operates as well as with who he would like to have access to the password-protected portions of the website.

.htaccess, or comparable if you're using nginx or some other web server, is certainly an option if your hosting provider allows it.

You may also integrate with a third-party authentication system like OpenID (http://openid.net/) or Google (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) or whatnot--these will often work without requiring any backend changes to Apache and such. This would also likely be less work than creating your own authentication backend.

If your client's users are all Google users, for example, then using Google's authentication system might be a more attractive option. The same would apply for other third-party authentication systems. (Note, too, that you can provide your users with access to multiple third-party authentication systems for more convenience, if necessary.)

I know this is an old thread, but hopefully these ideas provide some insight. :)